# postgresql バックアップ(backup)のロック状態(lock)について

Tags: postgresql

こんにちは、会社で毎日backupをとっていますが、backupだとlockレベルの一番低い「access share mode」だということを聞きました。

backupならおそらく、pg_dumpかpg_dumpallだと思うんですが、ネットのドキュメントを探しても見つかりません。
pg_dumpかpg_dumpall?の場合はaccess share modeとか記載の場所を教えてくれると助かります。
https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.1/html/index.html あたりがpostgresqlのドキュメントですよね？

出来ればurl教えてほしいです。日本語版でお願いします。

Comment: 参考 - ["pg_dump は ACCESS SHARE モード でテーブルレベルのロックを取得します。"](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/14863/3060)

Answer (score 1):

質問にあるpostgresqlのドキュメントの [24.1. SQLによるダンプ](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.1/html/backup-dump.html)のページに次の記載があります。この記載が、pg_dump, pg_dumpallが`access share mode`であることを示していると思われます。

> pg_dumpで作成されたダンプは、内部的に整合性があります。つまり、ダンプはpg_dumpが開始された際のデータベースのスナップショットを示しています。pg_dumpの操作はデータベースに対する他の作業を妨げません（ALTER TABLEのほとんどの形態であるような排他的ロックが必要な作業は例外です）。

> pg_dumpallはコマンドを発令することによりロール、テーブル空間、およびデータベースを再作成し、それぞれのデータベースに対してpg_dumpを起動します。このことは、それぞれのデータベースには内部的に矛盾がない一方、異なるデータベースのスナップショットは完全に同期しない可能性があることを示しています。